# How to fix Confluent Kafka Heap Size problem?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, heap-memory

I edited every parameter about the JVM heap size, but as you can see in the last line one of the process has 6GB of heap size, how to downgrade it and what is it for?

```
cp-kafk+    1121  3.8  4.1 5830780 341268 ?      Ssl  17:45   0:31 java -Xms256M -Xmx2G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties -cp /usr/share/java/kafka/*:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/*:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/*:/usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-telemetry/* -javaagent:/opt/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8077:/opt/prometheus/kafka_connect.yml org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed /etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties

cp-kafka    1126  0.3  1.0 4739976 84828 ?       Ssl  17:45   0:03 java -Xmx1g -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xlog:gc*:file=/var/log/kafka/zookeeper-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/zookeeper-log4j.properties -cp /usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-telemetry/* -javaagent:/opt/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8079:/opt/prometheus/zookeeper.yml org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties

cp-sche+    2456  2.0  3.2 4736916 264080 ?      Ssl  17:46   0:15 java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dschema-registry.log.dir=/var/log/confluent/schema-registry -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/schema-registry/log4j.properties -cp :/usr/bin/../package-schema-registry/target/kafka-schema-registry-package-*-development/share/java/schema-registry/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-security/schema-registry/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/schema-registry-plugins/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-common/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-telemetry/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/rest-utils/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/schema-registry/* -javaagent:/opt/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8078:/opt/prometheus/schema_registry.yml io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain /etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties


cp-kafka    2657 15.3  7.0 12331084 570984 ?     Ssl  17:57   0:19 java -Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xlog:gc*:file=/var/log/kafka/kafkaServer-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties -cp /usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-telemetry/* -javaagent:/opt/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8080:/opt/prometheus/kafka.yml kafka.Kafka /etc/kafka/server.properties
root        2807  0.0  0.0   6608  2328 pts/3    S+   17:59   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see production settings in Kafka documentation that LinkedIn recommends 6GB heap for their brokers. Unclear what you're trying to "fix" or the "problem" you're having, but you change it with an environment variable `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`, which you can find in `kafka-run-class.sh` script

If you're trying to reduce overall memory usage, then don't run Connect, Zookeeper, and Schema Registry all on the same machine